# How to sort Counter by value? - python

Tags: python, sorting, collections, counter

Other than doing list comprehensions of reversed list comprehension, is there a pythonic way to sort Counter by value? If so, it is faster than this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':7})
>>> sorted(x)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sorted(x.items())
[('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 7)]
>>> [(l,k) for k,l in sorted([(j,i) for i,j in x.items()])]
[('b', 3), ('a', 5), ('c', 7)]
>>> [(l,k) for k,l in sorted([(j,i) for i,j in x.items()], reverse=True)]
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)
```

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Use the [`Counter.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), it'll sort the items *for you*:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':7})
>>> x.most_common()
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
```

It'll do so in the most efficient manner possible; if you ask for a Top N instead of all values, a `heapq` is used instead of a straight sort:

```
>>> x.most_common(1)
[('c', 7)]
```

Outside of counters, sorting can always be adjusted based on a `key` function; `.sort()` and `sorted()` both take callable that lets you specify a value on which to sort the input sequence; `sorted(x, key=x.get, reverse=True)` would give you the same sorting as `x.most_common()`, but only return the keys, for example:

```
>>> sorted(x, key=x.get, reverse=True)
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

or you can sort on only the value given `(key, value)` pairs:

```
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
```

See the [Python sorting howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html) for more information.

Answer (score 54):

A rather nice addition to [@MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20950686/249341) answer is to get back a *dictionary* sorted by occurrence since `Collections.most_common` only returns a tuple. I often couple this with a json output for handy log files:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

x = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':7})
y = OrderedDict(x.most_common())
```

With the output:

```
OrderedDict([('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)])
{
  "c": 7, 
  "a": 5, 
  "b": 3
}
```

Comment: Starting from Python 3.7 (3.6 for CPython) there is no need for `OrderedDict` any more, because `dict` now keeps the insertion order. So it's simply `y = dict(x.most_common())`

Comment: @WalterTross Just to be clear, even in Python 3.7+, `OrderedDict` offers functionality that `dict` doesn't, especially regarding comparisons. For example, `OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]) == OrderedDict([('b', 2), ('a', 1)])` evaluates to False, whereas `{'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'b': 2, 'a': 1}` evaluates to True.

Comment: OrderedDict isn't the slightest bit more useful here compared to a plain dict. That includes the == check. Here the non-ordered dict does the right thing. Insertion order is that's desired in this instance. Sometimes yes, you want the order to change the result of the comparison.

I don't think the comment you replied to suggested OrderedDict wasn't needed for *anything* just that it wasn't needed here, and it's not. BTW JSON is effectively insertion-ordered even though it isn't in the spec.

Answer (score 24):

Yes:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':7})
```

Using the sorted keyword key and a lambda function:

```
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
[('b', 3), ('a', 5), ('c', 7)]
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
```

This works for all dictionaries. However `Counter` has a special function which already gives you the sorted items (from most frequent, to least frequent). It's called `most_common()`:

```
>>> x.most_common()
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
>>> list(reversed(x.most_common()))  # in order of least to most
[('b', 3), ('a', 5), ('c', 7)]
```

You can also specify how many items you want to see:

```
>>> x.most_common(2)  # specify number you want
[('c', 7), ('a', 5)]
```

Comment: Another way to reverse sort is to set the key function to `lamda i: -i[1]`

Comment: I had forgotten the `.items()` which then gave me `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`. It is just that you need the `items()` to make it read as a pair so that `k[1]` is found as the second item of each pair which can be reverse sorted with `-k[1]` because it is a number. You would not be able to do `-k[0]`  since `k[0]` is a string.

Answer (score 10):

More general sorted, where the `key` keyword defines the sorting method, minus before numerical type indicates descending:

```
>>> x = Counter({'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':7})
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda k: -k[1])  # Ascending
[('c', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: The `key` keyword defines the sorting method, minus before numerical type indicate descending