# Arrange elements with same count in alphabetical order

Tags: python, counter, python-collections

Python Collection `Counter.most_common(n)` method returns the top n elements with their counts. However, if the counts for two elements is the same, how can I return the result sorted by alphabetical order?

For example: for a string like: `BBBAAACCD`, for the "2-most common" elements, I want the result to be for specified `n = 2`:

```
[('A', 3), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]
```

and NOT:

```
[('B', 3), ('A', 3), ('C', 2)]
```

Notice that although `A` and `B` have the same frequency, `A` comes before `B` in the resultant list since it comes before `B` in alphabetical order.

```
[('A', 3), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Counter by value? - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950650/how-to-sort-counter-by-value-python)

Comment: @HarshaW no, it's not a duplicate. I just updated my question to clarify what I am trying to achieve. Please review and let me know if you have some thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is already a bit old i'd like to suggest a very simple solution to the problem which just involves sorting the input of *Counter()* before creating the Counter object itself. If you then call *most_common(n)* you will get the top *n* entries sorted in alphabetical order.

```py
from collections import Counter

char_counter = Counter(sorted('ccccbbbbdaef'))
for char in char_counter.most_common(3):
  print(*char)
```

resulting in the output:

```
b 4
c 4
a 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** issues here:

1. Include duplicates when considering top *n* most common values **excluding duplicates**.
2. For any duplicates, order alphabetically.

None of the solutions thus far address the first issue. You can use a heap queue with the `itertools` [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (also available in 3rd party libraries such as [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique)) to calculate the *n*th largest count.

Then use `sorted` with a custom key.

```
from collections import Counter
from heapq import nlargest
from toolz import unique

x = 'BBBAAACCD'

c = Counter(x)
n = 2
nth_largest = nlargest(n, unique(c.values()))[-1]

def sort_key(x):
    return -x[1], x[0]

gen = ((k, v) for k, v in c.items() if v >= nth_largest)
res = sorted(gen, key=sort_key)

[('A', 3), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first sort your output array in alphabetical order and than sort again by most occurrences which will keep the alphabetical order:

```
from collections import Counter
alphabetic_sorted = sorted(Counter('BBBAAACCD').most_common(), key=lambda tup: tup[0])
final_sorted = sorted(alphabetic_sorted, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
print(final_sorted[:3])
```

Output:

```
[('A', 3), ('B', 3), ('C', 2)]
```

Comment: it's don't work with `'qqweertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'` string

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I changed the solution to a more generic one that solves your example!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
sorted(Counter('AAABBBCCD').most_common(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
```

This sorts count descending (as they are already, which should be more performant) and then sorts by name ascending in each equal count group

Comment: But this doesn't include duplicates when user wants "top 2 values", e.g. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156058/9209546).

Comment: Oh that wasn't explicitly stated in the question

Comment: Possibly, but it's implicit in the output. I agree that the question could be more clearly written (I'll try to do that).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the problems I got in the interview exam and failed to do it. Came home slept for a while and solution came in my mind.

```
from collections import Counter


def bags(list):
    cnt = Counter(list)
    print(cnt)
    order = sorted(cnt.most_common(2), key=lambda i:( i[1],i[0]), reverse=True)
    print(order)
    return order[0][0]


print(bags(['a','b','c','a','b']))
```

Comment: but if you will use more elements in list the result don't sorted by alphabetical order, for example try use, `print(bags(['a','b','c','a','b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']))` and `most_common(3)` sometimes it returns `[('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 2)]` but i always wait `[('c', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 2)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


s = 'qqweertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'

s_list = list(s)

elements = Counter(s_list).most_common()

print(elements)
alphabet_sort = sorted(elements, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(alphabet_sort)
num_sort = sorted(alphabet_sort, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(num_sort)
```

if you need to get slice:

```
print(num_sort[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "BBBAAACCD"    
p = [(i,s.count(i)) for i in sorted(set(s))]
```

**If you are okay with not using the Counter.

Answer (score -2):

```
from collections import Counter
print(sorted(Counter('AAABBBCCD').most_common(3)))
```

This question seems to be a duplicate
[How to sort Counter by value? - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950650/how-to-sort-counter-by-value-python)

Comment: this doesn't work. If you make 'A' not the most common, it undoes the most_common and returns it in alphabetical order.