# Remove similar items in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you remove similar items in a list in Python but only for a given item.  Example,

```
l = list('need')
```

If 'e' is the given item then

```
l = list('nd')
```

The set() function will not do the trick since it will remove all duplicates.

count() and remove() is not efficient.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/q/20950650/6692898

Comment: You mean how to remove duplicate letters? The question is not clear enough, what dows "similar items" mean?

Comment: Please see example above.

Comment: Are you only wanting to remove a 'given item' if it is also a duplicate? What if the given removal letter is `'e'` what would you expect with `'nedd'`?

Comment: My question is clear enough, because I gave the input and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `filter`

assuming you write function that decide on the items that you want to keep in the list.

for your example

```
 def pred(x):
     return x!="e"
 l=list("need")
 l=list(filter(pred,l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `given = 'e'` and `l= list('need')`.

```
for i in range(l.count(given)):
    l.remove(given)
```

Comment: `count()` will count the `n` number of occurrences of an item in your list, allowing you to loop through the list with `remove()` `n` times.

Comment: OP said count and remove are inefficient

Comment: that wasn't in the question when i first answered it lol

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace `'e'` from the list of words in a list, you can use regex re.sub().  If you also want a count of how many occurrences of e were removed from each word, then you can use re.subn(). The first one will provide you strings in a list. The second will provide you a tuple (string, n) where n is the number of occurrences.

```
import re
lst = list(('need','feed','seed','deed','made','weed','said'))
j = [re.sub('e','',i) for i in lst]
k = [re.subn('e','',i) for i in lst]
```

The output for j and k are :

```
j = ['nd', 'fd', 'sd', 'dd', 'mad', 'wd', 'said']
k = [('nd', 2), ('fd', 2), ('sd', 2), ('dd', 2), ('mad', 1), ('wd', 2), ('said', 0)]
```

If you want to count the total changes made, just iterate thru k and sum it. There are other simpler ways too. You can simply use regEx

```
re.subn('e','',''.join(lst))[1]
```

This will give you total number of items replaced in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`List comprehension` Method. Not sure if the size/complexity is less than that of `count` and `remove`.

```
def scrub(l, given):
    return [i for i in l if i not in given]
```

Filter method, again i'm not sure

```
def filter_by(l, given):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x not in given, l))
```

Bruteforce with `recursion` but there are a lot of potential downfalls. Still an option. Again I don't know the size/comp

```
def bruteforce(l, given):
    try:
        l.remove(given[0])
        return bruteforce(l, given)
    except ValueError:
        return bruteforce(l, given[1:])
    except IndexError:
        return l
    return l
```

For those of you curious as to the actual time associated with the above methods, i've taken the liberty to test them below!

Below is the method I've chosen to use.

```
def timer(func, name):
    print("-------{}-------".format(name))
    try:
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        x = func()
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print((end-start).microseconds)
    except Exception, e:
        print("Failed: {}".format(e))
    print("\r")
```

The dataset we are testing against. Where `l` is our original list and `q` is the items we want to remove, and `r` is our expected result.

```
l = list("need"*50000)
q = list("ne")
r = list("d"*50000)
```

For posterity I've added the `count` / `remove` method the OP was against. (For good reason!)

```
def count_remove(l, given):
    for i in given:
        for x in range(l.count(i)):
            l.remove(i)
    return l
```

All that's left to do is test!

```
timer(lambda: scrub(l, q), "List Comp")
assert(scrub(l,q) == r)

timer(lambda: filter_by(l, q), "Filter")
assert(filter_by(l,q) == r)

timer(lambda : count_remove(l, q), "Count/Remove")
assert(count_remove(l,q) == r)

timer(lambda: bruteforce(l, q), "Bruteforce")
assert(bruteforce(l,q) == r)
```

And our results

> -------List Comp-------
> 10000
>
> -------Filter-------
> 28000
>
> -------Count/Remove-------
> 199000
>
> -------Bruteforce-------
> Failed: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

The `Recursion` method failed with a larger dataset, but we expected this. I tested on smaller datasets, and `Recursion` is marginally slower. I thought it would be faster.